# Increase the size/height of the OpenLayer map/canvas

Tags: canvas, mapping, openlayers

I'm trying to let the Map/Canvas height of OpenLayers 100%, but I'm not able to do it.

I've already tried putting in several places the "height: 100%;" and used the "map.updateSize()" function, but without success. I already tried to use "height: 100vh;" as well, but it stretches the map instead of increasing the canvas.

I send print screen below illustrating what happens:

[image]

I would like the height of the map/canvas to be 100% on the page

That piece of code showed on the image:

```
<div id="map" class="olMap">
    <div class="ol-viewport" data-view="146" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; touch-action: none;">

        <canvas class="ol-unselectable" width="937" height="480" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;"></canvas>

        <div class="ol-overlaycontainer"></div>
        <div class="ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent">
        <div class="ol-zoom ol-unselectable ol-control">
        <button class="ol-zoom-in" type="button" title="Zoom in">+</button>
        <button class="ol-zoom-out" type="button" title="Zoom out">−</button>
        </div>
        <div class="ol-rotate ol-unselectable ol-control ol-hidden">                
        <button class="ol-rotate-reset" type="button" title="Reset rotation"><span class="ol-compass" style="transform: rotate(0rad);">⇧</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="ol-attribution ol-unselectable ol-control ol-collapsed" style="display: none;"><ul></ul><button type="button" title="Attributions"><span>i</span></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Code where I create the map (Explore.vue):

```
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    initMap: function () {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      this.map = new Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          layerGroupBaseMap
        ],
        view: new View({
          projection: 'EPSG:4326',
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 5
        })
      })
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.initMap()
  },
  ...
}
```

Source code: https://github.com/rmmariano/executive_frontend/tree/dev-rodrigo

Does someone have any idea?

PS: I've already asked this question in gis.stackexchange.com [1], but in the OpenLayers site says to ask here in stackoverflow, for that reason, I'm adding this question here.

[1] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314059/increase-the-size-height-of-the-openlayer-map-canvas

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include

```
<style>
    html, body, .olmap {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Checking with Chrome's devtools is pointless as the devtools reduces the available page size for the application so the map will be scaled down.  But you can check with Edge:

[image]

1680 x 977 as expected on a 1680 x 1050 display allowing for the top bars

Comment: Even when I'm with full screen (without devtools), the map does not fill entire page in both Chrome and Firefox (example [1]). Maybe is it because of the monitor resolution? I've already tried to add your code, but no success.
[1] https://github.com/rmmariano/executive_frontend/blob/dev-rodrigo/docs/white_bar.png

Comment: Have you tried running the OpenLayers example? https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mobile-full-screen.html